# Internal column name reference not working in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-2007

I tried to retrieve a lookup column from a list. The list name is "Colors" and the lookup column name is "RedPencilBox:E-Mail"; however, I am getting the "error in controller 2" alert. I wonder if this is because of the length of the internal name of "RedPencilBox:E-Mail"(?).

```js
var module2 = angular.module('App2', []);
module2.controller('Controller2', function ($scope, $http) { 
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Colors')/items?$select=Title, Id, RedPencilBox%5Fx003A%5FE%5Fx002d%5FMail/EMail&$expand=RedPencilBox%5Fx003A%5FE%5Fx002d%5FMail/EMail",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
  }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.project = data.d.results;
  }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    alert("error in Controller2");
  });
});
```

Comment: I have tried another lookup column in the same list as 'RedPencilBox:E-Mail' and it also looks up to the column in the same list as 'EMail'; it works fine... Then I gave up and create a new lookup column to look up 'EMail' instead of using the old lookup column (RedPencilBox:E-Mail) to look up 'EMail'. It surprisingly works fine (no controller error and do whatever I implement)! Even the length of the internal name of the new lookup column is longer. However, I still do not understand why the former lookup column does not work. Is there any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Try your request url right in a browser. It should return an exact error, maybe you'll get a clue.
Also try this url without query parameters: "*webURL + /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Colors')/items*" - to see if your field's internal name is exactly the same you have in the query url. 
I don't think you need encoding here: just try pass it as it is: **RedPencilBox_x003A_E_x002d_Mail**

Best regards, Polina

Comment: No, it should be internal name.

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer since it is giving suggestions what to try but might not be the answer.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer since I don't have enough reputation points to add comments to questions.